# Unable to put object into S3 bucket after assuming role

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I see the below error when trying to put an object into S3 bucket in a different account after assuming role. However I was able to list all the objects under the bucket.

> "errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the
>   PutObject operation: Access Denied",   "errorType": "ClientError",
>   botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when
>   calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied

**Code**

```
        session_assumed = aws_session(role_arn=ROLE_ARN, session_name='my_lambda')
        bucket = '<bucket name>'
        bucket_resource = session_assumed.resource('s3').Bucket(bucket)
        // The below works - able to read values from the bucket
        for object in bucket_resource.objects.all():
            print(' object value = {}'.format(object.key))
        // the below does not work
        bucket_resource.put_object(Key='<key>', Body=b'Hello World!')
```

I checked the policy document in the assumed role present in other account and it seems to provide full access to s3

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "<sid name>",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket name>-*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**EDIT : Working Code**

```
d0_bucket_resource.put_object(Key='<key>', Body=b'Hello World!',ServerSideEncryption='AES256')
```

Comment: Did you make a typo in the value you put under resource in the policy document? The dash(-) should have been a forward slash(/).

Comment: No , I have few buckets with names -000 , -001 etc, Hence the resource has -*

Comment: You will need to specify the resource in the format `arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*` to grant permission to all objects in the bucket for operations on objects.

Comment: I'm still able to read makes me believe that may not be the issue. I'm trying to check if there are any other policies that blacklist the access.

Comment: Based on what you describe, it should be working.

Comment: found the issue - I was missing ServerSideEncryption='AES256'. It started working after I added it

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein & junkangli